# htaccess rewrite query string vs back reference?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, opencart

I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
http://www.domain.com/johns-wishlist-12
```

to this:

```
index.php?route=wishlist/shared_wishlist&id=12&name=johns
```

I've read some good tutorials, but none of them really explain how back references work (when using more than one)... I also don't understand when to use {QUERY_STRING}, as opposed to just back references?

Could use a little help... this is what I have for the above:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)-wishlist-([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?route=wishlist/shared_wishlist&id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Obviously "johns" and "12" will change based on the user... 
so should I be using a rewrite condition {QUERY_STRING} in this case? why?

Comment: The rule You wrote is fine. It does exactly what You intended. No need for conditions on query-string. Condition on `{QUERY_STRING}` needs to be used when you need to rewrite depending on parameters originally passed in query string (which is not your case).

Comment: I think $1 and $2 are not in right place here. Try: RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)-wishlist-([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?route=wishlist/shared_wishlist&id=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Thanks guys, I just figured out that $1 and $2 are simply the order in which the (brackets) are listed in the rewrite... I reversed them and it worked great... though, I'm still not very clear on when to use QueryString... my example shows static strings, but they are variable and will change... what's the difference between that and "depending on parameters originally passed in query string"??? Tutorial links welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable is used to **match against** the request's query string. In your case, the request is for `http://www.example.com/johns-wishlist-12`, so there is no query string there. You are rewriting *to* a URI with a query string, though, so the only thing that matters is the next time around when the rules loop (which may not happen), if you had another rule that matched against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable, the query string that you created will show up there.

The `$` something in your rule's target are backreferences to a "grouped" match in the rule's pattern. Whenever you have a `()` in your pattern, that groups the match which can then be backreferenced using a `$`. In the case of a condition, the backreferences are `%` instead.

Comment: Although everyone was helpful (thanks doods!!), this response actually answers the question title... much appreciated everyone!!